# presentModalViewController from a ViewController nested in a UIScrollview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I am creating an iPhone app and have an issue with running code for presentModalViewController from a viewController which is nested in a Scrollview, when I click the button to present the next view controller I get a slow animation and a blank screen for two seconds.

From my AppDelegate I am setting the rootViewController to my ViewController (which contains the code to set my scrollview layout)

I'm basically loading two view controllers inside a scrollview so that the user can pull down the screen to see the history.

**AppDelegateCode**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

{

```
[application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque];  

self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
ViewController *controller =  [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
self.window.rootViewController = controller; //self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

}

**ViewController Code**

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

```
CGRect bounds = self.view.bounds;

vScroller.bounces = NO;
vScroller.pagingEnabled = YES;
vScroller.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = FALSE;
vScroller.alwaysBounceVertical = FALSE;

vScroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height * 2);

// History View Controller..
historyViewController *historyView = [[historyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"historyViewController" bundle:nil];

[vScroller addSubview:historyView.view];
[historyView release];

// Reconfigure Content Offset
vScroller.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, bounds.size.height);

// Calculator View Controller
mainCalculatorViewController *mainView = [[mainCalculatorViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"mainCalculatorViewController" bundle:nil];
mainView.view.frame = CGRectOffset(bounds, 0, bounds.size.height);
[vScroller addSubview:mainView.view];
```

}

**mainCalculatorViewController info Button Code**

```
  - (IBAction)btnInfo:(id)sender 
    {
        infoViewController *controller = [[infoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"infoViewController" bundle:nil];

        controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
        [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
        [controller release];
    }
```

The problem is when clicking the info button I get the bad animation, it seems to me that perhaps the button and presentModal View Controller should be ran from the parent ViewController which holds the nested scrollviews but I am unsure of how to do this.

Any tips or suggestions would be great.

Thanks Aaron

Answer (score -1):

First of all i don't know how interface builder does this. But programmatically you should probably want to make a new navigationController to handle the modalVC.

```
-(void)showModalVC
{
    self.myModalVC = [[ModalVC alloc] init];

    self.myModalVC.dismissDelegate = self;

    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                             initWithRootViewController:self.myModalVC];

    navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet; //or something similar, this one is used on an iPad

    UILabel *navTopItemTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 44)];
    navTopItemTitle.text = @"Modal shizzle";
    navTopItemTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    navTopItemTitle.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    navTopItemTitle.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;

    [navController.navigationBar.topItem setTitleView:navTopItemTitle];

    [self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];

    [self.addTabViewController release];
    [navController release];
}
```

This is how I work with ModalVC's.

I hope it's usefull to you.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the code, I have tried this out but I am still getting a black screen when clicking the info button, it certainly seems something to do with the view controller and it's button being nested inside a scrollview which is on another view controller :/

Comment: Well the black screen is something that you do inside your modalVC. The info there can and should be set in properties INBETWEEN the alloc of the modalVC and the presentModalVC. Or in the loadView of the modalVC itself. That you get a blackscreen is not a presentModalVC problem anymore but mainly a mistake in setting the view of your ModalVC.

Comment: hmm I'm not sure what it is, your code works perfect in terms of showing the info View Controller but from the initial view when I click the info button the screen goes black for 2 seconds then shows the info view the transition animation also does not play either.

Comment: That seems a different question tho. I suggest updating the question and adding the code on how you show your modalVC or make a new question all together. It seems however that you set the data after you loaded your modalVC and after the viewDidAppear:-method which means you loaded the data at the moment the view is already in the screen.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have updated the question and posted code from AppDelegate, ViewController & mainCalculatorViewController which is where my button is.